# Expected value of function of continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with PDF $f(x)=\mathbb{P} \left( X \le x \right)$. Let g be some function. Then $g(X)$ is a random variable.

Then
$\mathbb{E} \left( g(X) \right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)f(x)dx$.

I'm finding this harder to prove than the discrete case. Here's how I started:
$\mathbb{E} \left( g(X) \right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \mathbb{P} \left(g(X) \le g(x) \right)dg(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \mathbb{P} \left(g(X) \le g(x) \right)g'(x)dx$

How should I continue to get the result?

Comment: You sure $f(x) = \mathbb P(X \le x)$? Shouldn't $f$ be the density?

Comment: You can see [here](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/mean-lotus.html#:~:text=Theorem%3A%20Let%20X%20be%20a,function%20of%20this%20random%20variable.&text=E%5Bg(X)%5D,(1)) towards the end for a proof.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon In that link they make additional assumptions. The result is true whenever $X$ has a density and $g(X)$ has finite mean.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Good point, indeed the best way is the way you mention.

Answer (score 1):

$Eg(X)=\int g(x)dF_X(x)$ : This holds when $g=I_A$ , hence when $g$ is  a simple function, hence when $g$ is  a non-negative measurable function or an integrable function w.r.t. $F_X$. So, if $g(X)$ has finite mean, then $Eg(X)=\int g(x)f(x)dx$ where $f$ is the density of $X$ (not the distribution function).